# In Pentaho can I load file and proccess the data directly into oracle database.

Tags: sftp, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

As of now i am downloading the file from SFTP to local and then adding into the database.I want to remove the extra step that is to download the file to machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Text file input` step is based on Apache vfs, which can read from a sftp server. So the solution is to define the `Filename/Directory` with the appropriate syntax:

```
sftp://[ username[: password]@] hostname[: port][ relative-path]
```

Supported file systems are on the [Apache Common VFS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html#SFTP) web page.